# Online Python interpreter? Internet explorer 8

Tags: python, internet-explorer-8, interpreter

Are there any sites like Trinket that allow you to run python code and are Internet Explorer 8 compatible?

I haven't been able to find any.

I am trying to work on a project on my work computer... downloads are blocked so online is the only option. Also stuck with Internet Explorer 8 which too outdated for Trinket

Comment: What about this one? http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `repl.it` :

http://repl.it/languages/python3

It's for Python 3.x .For other versions:

https://ideone.com/

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

https://www.python.org/shell/

http://pythonfiddle.com/

Comment: these look promising for other users - unfortunately they are blocked on my PC

Comment: Thank you. I had tried a few of these before but all are either blocked or fail to run :( I hope the links can be useful to other users

Comment: You can try to download other browser like Firefox or Google Chrome and try those links...

Comment: I did - the downloads of these browsers is also blocked! Looks like they really don't want me playing with python here

Comment: None of these support `turtle`. Trinket at least partially supports it (or fully if you pay for membership).